# Broken configuration in Mongo on ubuntu - cannot start mongod with correct config

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I have managed to break what was a stable instance of Mongo running on an Ubuntu server.

It doesn't seem to start the service using the correct config.

Running `mongod` gives me the following:

`2016-11-01T16:06:27.853+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`

and therefore, when I try to run the mongo shell I get:

`2016-11-01T16:06:48.476+0000 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused`

The config file at /etc/mongod.conf states the dbpath as `/var/lib/mongod` which has a bunch of dbses already in there (which were working!) and the port as 3306.  This is clearly not what the error messages above are pointing to.

I've tried running mongod with this config file using `--config /etc/mongod.conf` but I get this:

`2016-11-01T16:09:12.530+0000 F CONTROL  Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"`

Any ideas of what steps I can take to restore the original service on the right dbpath and port?

There is an upstart file at `/etc/init/mongod.conf` but a server reboot hasn't had any impact.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When running mongod with data files on a low disk space volume (typically I had this issue on my always crowded development laptop), you may experience the above, with the slightly misleading symptoms. From memory, the required space in my/our case was around a few gigabytes, 3 typically sufficed.

If this fits, you can either choose to delete files, or to ignore (since you aren't in a production environment), use the --smallfiles option, see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/).

(I just noticed that this issue is about 2 years old ... possibly only relates to the mmapv1 engine, which isn't the default since 3.2. Having written it, I'll post this possible answer anyway, probably won't be of much use though by now :) )